# Positioning in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, slider

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="slider" class="images">
<img src="img/image1.png" height=200 width=200>
    <p>Image1 corresponding text here</p>    
<img src="img/image2.png" height=200 width=200>
    <p>Image2 corresponding text here</p>    
<img src="img/image3.png" height=200 width=200>
    <p>Image3 corresponding text here</p>
```

```
<div class="switch_image">
<a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

1. How can I change the text location to be to the right of the image and not below it?
2. After the above question is answered, the images will be stacked on top of each other, so how can I space the images apart by a certain margin?
3. Once all this is done, how can I get each image and it's corresponding text to move with respect to their original position when I re-size the broswer window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest wrapping the images and text:

```
<div id="slider" class="images">
    <div class="single-image">
        <img src="img/image1.png" height=200 width=200>
        <p>Image1 corresponding text here</p>   
    </div>

    <div class="single-image">
        <img src="img/image1.png" height=200 width=200>
        <p>Image1 corresponding text here</p>   
    </div>

    <div class="single-image">
        <img src="img/image1.png" height=200 width=200>
        <p>Image1 corresponding text here</p>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS do something like:

```
.images { overflow: hidden; /* dirty way of self-clearing floats */ }

.single-image { 
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

.single-image img { 
    float: left;
}

.single-image p {
    float: right;
    width: 90px;
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/alobiw/1/edit

Comment: How can I make the text not go onto the next line, but keep going to the right? (thanks so much btw for the help! :D)

Comment: No worries! I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I guess you may just increase the width of image wrapper? Example: http://jsbin.com/alobiw/4/edit

Answer (score 1):

Set the display property to `inline-block` on the `p` tag.

```
   p{
      display: inline-block;
    }
```